# Implementing two dependent classes (forward declaration of class)

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a problem implementing two classes that use each other in their definitions and implementations. I mean they're both dependent on each other.

Here they are:

Class Course:

```
class Course {
        int courseId;
        int maxSignedStudents;
        int numOfStudentsSigned;
        AVLTree<Student*> signedStudents;
        Queue<Student*> waitingQueue;
    public:
        Course(int courseId, int size);
        int getFreeSpots() {                    
            return maxSignedStudents - numOfStudentsSigned;
        }
        void addStudent(Student* newStudent);
        int getId();    //TODO: Added this func
        void removeFromSignedStudents(int studentId);


        class CourseIsFull: std::exception {};

    };
```

class Student:

```
class Student {
    int id;
    AVLTree<Course*> signedCourses; 
                                        //and not "Course"
    AVLTree<QueueNode<Student*>* > waitingCourses;
public:
    Student(int studentId);
    int getId();                    
    void addSignedCourse(Course* newCourse); 
    void addToWaitingCourses(int courseId, QueueNode<Student*>* newCourse); 
    Course* getSignedCourse(int courseId);
    void removeFromSignedCourses(int courseId);

};
```

Now I added a forward declaration inside Course.h like this:

```
class Student;
```

There are functions inside course that use functions from student and vice-versa. So because of that I get a forward declaration error saying: 
forward declaration of 'class Student'

**How can I implement these two classes so they know each other right from the moment I define each one and not get an error..**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine. In course.h you can forward declare `class Student;`, and in student.h you can forward declare `class Course;`. The error you specify can only occur if you actually define the class and then declare it, which could be the result of the order in which you include files. Ensure that any forward declarations precede the inclusion of the actual definition (an `#include` is nothing more than a fancy way of 'inline adding' a literal other file), and the error will disappear.

Comment: Also header guards will be helpful here.

Comment: thanks. I actually solved this in a weird way:

In Course.h: 

    #include "Student.h"

    class Course {...}

And in student.h:

    class Course;

    class Student {...}

    #include "Course.h"

Answer (score -1):

See you have two options

1 
Make two cpp files and two header files each containing one class defintion and their member function defintions in cpp files and in each  of the .cpp files include their respective files

In one of the header files include header file of other class.

In the main function file include the header file of the former class in previous step

2
Or keep everything in one file

But just before a class defintion declare the second class for example

class FirstHello;

class SecondHello
{
  CLASS DEF
};

class Firsthello
{
 class defintion
};